# Wifi drivers install

Tags: drivers

I’ve recently installed Ubuntu (which has just upgraded to 19.10) on a asrock DeskMini A300 (this includes a wifi module). As I have been a long time Windows user certain elements of Ubuntu/Linux I have no experience of Ubuntu and am more than a bit lost.

‘Software and Updates’ tells me that

intel corporation dual band wireless-ac3168ngw [stone peak]
this device is not working

I’m given one option
continue using manually installed driver

this intel site gives Linux drivers 
https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html
Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168  drivers are available to download but it mentions ‘kernels’ and I dont know what difference that makes ?

Are they the correct drivers and how would I install them. If not the correct drivers were would I find and how would I install. 
(instructions are going to have to be fairly specific and idiot proof)

Any help gratefully received

Graham

My kernel is 5.3.0-19-generic
thanks for the info on how to find this

Have done a bit more research
Just to have a look I downloaded from intel the firmware for ‘Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168’ which is ‘iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz’  unzipped and inside is ‘iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode’.

Within computer/lib/firmware iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode already exists ?

As  iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode already exists within Ubuntu should it not just ‘run’ (or what ever the correct term is) or do I have to do something.

I’m a bit lost as to what to do next

Comment: Those iwlwifi drivers are also in the ubuntu repositories: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=iwlwifi . please use that one. It will only let you install the correct version. Oh and `uname -a` will show you your kernel number ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you issue command at **Terminal**:

> uname -r

The **kernel** version will be shown:

> 5.0.0-32-generic

Currently I am using the **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS** and have upgraded to 5.0.0-32-generic,
that why it show 5.0.0-32-generic

So from the website provided by you [Intel](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html):

```
Device: Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168       
Kernels: 4.6+
Firmware: iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
```

The wireless adapter is seemed to be tested on Kernel 4.6+.

Comment: My kernel is 5.3.0-19-generic
thanks for the info on how to find this

Have done a bit more research
Just to have a look I downloaded from intel the firmware for ‘Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168’ which is ‘iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz’  unzipped and inside is ‘iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode’.

Within computer/lib/firmware iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode already exists ? 

As  iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode already exists within Ubuntu should it not just ‘run’ (or what ever the correct term is) or do I have to do something.

I’m a bit lost as to what to do next

Comment: Perhaps you can try to debug following the way in this page?
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/debugging

Or you may follow the ways provided in the comment by @Rinzwind.

Comment: just looked at that link (thanks for providing) and now my head hurts, much of it is like a really difficult foreign language :) However it might/should be useful, i'll just have to persevere - the learning curve persists.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to get the driver to work. stuck a micro Bluetooth dongle in and both mouse and keyboard worked without problem.
maybe a future OS update will fix the problem - but for now i can focus on the next Ubuntu problem